# Precise definition/construction of $\text{Sym}(\text{Sym}^2)$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

The question title basically has my question. What is the precise definition/construction of$$\text{Sym}(\text{Sym}^2),$$as mentioned in the following?

http://aimpl.org/repnstability/1/

If possible, I would like this to be self-contained and not defer to other stuff about twisted commutative algebras, as much as they are interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan Petersen points out, it's impossible to answer this question without talking about twisted commutative algebras. Moreover, to talk about TCAs over $\mathbb{Z}$, you need a more general definition of TCAs (which becomes equivalent to the earlier Sam-Snowden definitions when you're over $\mathbb{C}$). I'm not sure this is in the literature, so I'll try to explain.

**Definition:** A TCA is a commutative algebra inside the tensor category of FB-modules.

Let's expand this definition. FB denotes the category of finite sets and bijections, and an FB-module is a functor $W: \mathrm{FB}\to \mathbb{Z}\mathrm{-Mod}$. In other words, $W$ is essentially a collection of $S_n$-representations $W_n$ (one for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$), with no relation between them.

The disjoint union of finite sets $\sqcup:\mathrm{FB}\times \mathrm{FB}\to \mathrm{FB}$ induces a tensor product $\otimes:\mathrm{FB}\mathrm{-Mod}\times \mathrm{FB}\mathrm{-Mod}\to \mathrm{FB}\mathrm{-Mod}$ (often called the "convolution tensor product". It has the universal property that a map of FB-modules $A\otimes B\to C$ is equivalent to a collection of maps $A_S\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B_T\to C_{S\sqcup T}$ for all finite sets $S$ and $T$, natural in $S$ and $T$. (Equivalently, you can say it's a collection of $S_k\times S_\ell$-equivariant maps $A_k\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B_\ell\to C_{k+\ell}$, but it's easier to keep track of things like the symmetry $A\otimes B\cong B\otimes A$ with the former definition.)

A TCA is an FB-module $A$ together with a multiplication $A\otimes A\to A$ (which has to be commutative, but this is a property not structure so we don't need to stress it).

---

Now we can define $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Sym}^2)$. Recall that a perfect matching on a set $T$ is an equivalence relation on $T$ where each equivalence class has exactly 2 elements.

**Definition:** $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Sym}^2)$ is the FB-module $A$ which assigns to a finite set $T$ the free abelian group $A_T=\mathbb{Z}[\{\text{perfect matchings on }T\}]$.

To make this a TCA, we need to define the multiplication map $A\otimes A\to A$. According to the universal property above, this means we have to specify natural maps $A_S\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A_T\to A_{S\sqcup T}$. But this is very easy: if you have a perfect matching of $S$, and a perfect matching of $T$, their union is a perfect matching of $S\sqcup T$.

---

From this perspective the name may not be so clear. Here are two explanations. First (and perhaps less satisfying for you?): Define an FB-module $X$ by $X_T=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&\text{if }\lvert T\rvert=1\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$. Because we have a tensor product, we can make sense of $\textrm{Sym}^k$ in FB-Mod, and for example $\textrm{Sym}^2 X$ turns out to be $(\textrm{Sym}^2 X)_T=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}&\text{if }\lvert T\rvert=2\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$. Moreover, our algebra $A$ is precisely $\textrm{Sym}^*(\textrm{Sym}^2 X)=\bigoplus_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\textrm{Sym}^k(\textrm{Sym}^2 X)$.

Alternately, if you were to work over $\mathbb{C}$ throughout, then there is an alternate description of TCAs over $\mathbb{C}$ in terms of polynomial representations of $\textrm{GL}_\infty(\mathbb{C})$. (See e.g. Section 2.1 of [arXiv:1501.06925](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06925v2).) In this perspective, you are looking at nothing other than the commutative ring $\textrm{Sym}^*(\textrm{Sym}^2 \mathbb{C}^\infty)$, with its natural multiplication and natural $\textrm{GL}_\infty(\mathbb{C})$-action.

Comment: Hi Tom, this definition is definitely in the literature. I don't know the history well, but Joyal's "Foncteurs analytiques et espèces de structures" (1986) talks systematically about twisted commutative, associative and Lie algebras in these terms; twisted Lie and associative algebras were considered earlier by Barratt "Twisted Lie algebras" (1978). In terms of operads, a twisted algebra over an operad (e.g. Com, Ass or Lie) is the same thing as a left module over that operad, which gives another name under which these gadgets have been studied.

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly explained in Section 6.3 of the reference

[W] Jerzy Weyman, *Cohomology of Vector Bundles and Syzygies*, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2003.

Ler $X^s$ be the space of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Then the affine coordinate ring $A^{s}=\mathbb{K}[X^s]$ of $X^s$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring, more precisely by the symmetry condition we have
\begin{equation*} 
A^s \simeq \mathbb{K}[\phi_{ij}]_{\, 1\leq i \leq j \leq n}, 
\end{equation*}
where $\phi_{ij}$ denotes the $ij$-coordinate function on $X^s$.

On the other hand, we may identify $X^s$ with the space $\mathrm{Sym}^2  E^*$, where $E$ is the vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{K}$, hence   we obtain
\begin{equation*} 
A^s \simeq \mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Sym}^2E^*).
\end{equation*}

Comment: I am not sure the classical multilinear algebra definition is what the OP asks for but the new angle coming from the recent work of Church, Farb, Snowden etc.I would be interested in learning on this particular example what differences there are between these notions, if any.

Comment: Maybe you are right, anyway the question is not particularly clear about this point.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a silly question to be honest. The name "Sym(Sym^2)" refers to a particular twisted commutative algebra. It doesn't make sense to define what it means without using the word twisted commutative algebra.

In any case, the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06925v2 of Nagpal-Sam-Snowden defines the twisted commutative algebra $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathbf C^\infty))$ and proves that it is noetherian. Tom Church's question in Problem 1.5 on the linked page asks if this is true also with $\mathbf Z$-coefficients. I suggest you try to read that paper (and/or other papers like https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5122), try to understand what a twisted commutative algebra is, and then ask a more focused question.

Francesco's answer is on point, by the way: one possible definition of a twisted commutative algebra is that it is a polynomial functor from vector spaces to commutative rings. The assignment $E^\ast \mapsto A^s$ in Francesco's answer is the polynomial functor that Nagpal-Sam-Snowden prove is noetherian.

Comment: I think there is a small issue with your second paragraph. The definition of TCA given in that Nagpal-Sam-Snowden paper only makes sense over $\mathbb{C}$. In general you have to define it differently to make sense of TCAs over $\mathbb{Z}$ (and in particular, to make sense of my question about whether Sym(Sym^2) over $\mathbb{Z}$ is Noetherian). Since Sam-Snowden started out only working over $\mathbb{C}$, I'm not sure this general definition appears in the literature (although it is familiar to people in the area). I'll try to write up a longer explanation tonight.

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks for the comment! You're right that the definitions in terms of $\mathrm{GL}_\infty$ or polynomial functors from vector spaces to rings only work over a field of characteristic zero.